# My Mac can't boot Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, uefi, refit

Yesterday, I ran my Ubuntu Live CD to check if my OS partition was damaged, as I halted the computer from the Mac's button too much times. It seemed to be fine, so I restarted the computer. But now I can't boot from any Ubuntu media, when booting from the HD or the CD the screen just stays black. What can I do?

**UPDATE**: the CD sometimes runs and ables me to boot from HD's Ubuntu... it's surely an EFI problem.

iMac 21'5'' Late 2009

Latest version of rEFInd (after removing rEFIt)

Ubuntu 12.04 AMD64+MAC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved. I don't know if it was thanks to rEFInd, to `grub-install` or to the Mac itself, but now I can boot Ubuntu as used to :)

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Could you please be more specific as to what you did exactly? Did you reinstall rEFInd or remove it? How did you run `grub-install`? I'd appreciate the info very much.

Comment: Hi, @con-f-use! Let me explain you

Comment: 1) I removed rEFIt and installed rEFInd, as explained in the post.

Comment: 2) I tried to reconfigure GRUB with a Live CD (which just worked very few times), but it was 32 bits and my Mac is 64 bits. Anyway, I was able to boot my HD from that CD, so I just ran `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`

Answer (score 0):

Like espectalll123 has sad, I could make Ubuntu Precise boot on Macbook 5,2 after reinstalling Refind and reinstalling grub. But the last just was possible with this command after mounting the partitions:

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda
```

From: http://www.webupd8.org/2009/12/how-to-recover-grub2-linux.html